# For rig control in fldigi, ttySn available, but no ttyUSBn

Tags: linux-mint, ttyusb

I'm using LMDE Cinnamon-64bit ver 2.0.14 Linux kernel 3.11.2-amd64, trying to manage rig control from fldigi 3.21.83.  The dropdown list of Devices in fldigi only gives me dev/ttySn/.  I have a USB to serial cable to my radio.  How do I access /dev/ttyUSBn/?  I found my USB - serial adapter with lsusb (I have Vender and Product numbers), but it doesn't show up in the fldigi rig control menu.